# Linq search text using 'and' operator

Tags: linq, search, operator-keyword

I have a one to many relationship in the following tables

**Products** [ProductId, Name(varchar)]

**Keywords** [KeywordId, Keyword(varchar)]

**KeywordsToProducts**[Id, ProductId, KeywordId]

Let's say that search text is "blue pro". I need to search for both keywords using operator 'and'.
If I do the following:

```
string test="blue pro";
string[]words = test.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var query = from p in Products 

join kp in KeywordsToProducts on p.ProductId equals kp.ProductId 

join kw in Keywords on kp.KeywordId equals kw.KeywordId 

where (words.All(x=>kw.Keyword.Contains(x)))
```

then I don't geet anything because field keyword contains only one word.

How can I join the 'Keywrods.Keyword' db field records in order to search using 'and' operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join each matching `KeywordsToProducts` to `Keywords` you can gather them up and compare them:

```
var query = from p in Products
            join kp in KeywordsToProducts on p.ProductId equals kp.ProductId into kpj
            let kws = (from kp in kpj join kw in Keywords on kp.KeywordId equals kw.KeywordId select kw.Keyword)
            where words.All(w => kws.Any(kw => kw.Contains(w)))
            select p;
```

However, I think it is easier to understand (and possibly more efficient) if you do the `KeywordsToProducts` to `Keywords` `join` separately and first (note that it shows the join table would have been better named `KeywordIdsToProductIds`):

```
var kwToProducts = from kp in KeywordsToProducts
                   join kw in Keywords on kp.KeywordId equals kw.KeywordId
                   select new { kp.ProductId, kw.Keyword };

var query = from p in Products
            join kwp in kwToProducts on p.ProductId equals kwp.ProductId into kwpj
            where words.All(w => kwpj.Any(kwp => kwp.Keyword.Contains(w)))
            select p;
```

While I'm not (necessarily) a fan of mentioning it, also note EF navigation properties can hide the join table and make this query easier as well.

It would be something like:

```
var query = from p in Products
            where words.All(w => p.Keywords.Any(k => k.Contains(w)))
            select p;
```

I am assuming you meant to use `String.Contains` so users can type in parts of keywords and still find matches. If you want to require all of the keyword to be matched, here is the same code:

```
var query = from p in Products
            join kp in KeywordsToProducts on p.ProductId equals kp.ProductId into kpj
            let kws = (from kp in kpj join kw in Keywords on kp.KeywordId equals kw.KeywordId select kw.Keyword)
            where words.All(w => kws.Contains(w))
            select p;
```

Splitting subjoin:

```
var kwToProducts = from kp in KeywordsToProducts
                   join kw in Keywords on kp.KeywordId equals kw.KeywordId
                   select new { kp.ProductId, kw.Keyword };

var query = from p in Products
            join kwp in kwToProducts on p.ProductId equals kwp.ProductId into kwpj
            where words.All(w => kwpj.Select(kwp => kwp.Keyword).Contains(w))
            select p;
```

EF Navigation Property:

```
var query = from p in Products
            where words.All(w => p.Keywords.Contains(w))
            select p;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.It worked !!! Could you please take a look at my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516773/linq-search-text-using-and-operator-in-joined-fields-from-diferrent-tables                                                     Thanks