# Linq search text using 'and' operator in joined fields from different tables

Tags: linq, search

Thanks NetMage for answering my question in [Linq search text using 'and' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515621/linq-search-text-using-and-operator)

Now, please let me ask some more complicated:

I have the following tables where `localizationdata.EntryId` is linked to `mascotcategories.Id` and `mascots.Id` depending on the `localizationdata.Type` value.

```
`localizationdata` (
  `Id` int(11)`, Type` varchar(45),
  `EntryId` int(11),
  `LanguageId` int(11),
  `Value` varchar(150) }

`mascots` (
  `Id` int(11), `Name` varchar(100),
  `MascotCategoryId` int(11),
  `UserId` varchar(100),


`mascotcategories` (
  `Id` int(11), `CategoryName` varchar(45),
  `IsVisible` bit(1),
  `ParentId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SawgrassOnly` bit(1)
```

I need again to 'AND' search (as in my previous question in the link above) the `localizationdata.value` which contains the translated word for `mascotcategories.CategoryName` and `mascots.Name`.

For example, the user would enter French keywords "bleu ici" in which the 'bleu ' comes from `localizationdata.Value` that has the translated category name and 'ici' comes from `localizationdata.Value` too that has the mascot's translated name. I need the mascots that contain both the above words to their name and to their categories' name. Is this feasible?

Comment: What does "mascots.Id depending on the localizationdata.Type" mean? What do you mean by "depending on"?

Comment: A localizationdata row could be
 `Id` = 1,
 Type = 'mascot'
  `EntryId` = 34,
  `LanguageId` = 1,
  `Value` = 'bleu'                                                                                               

    Another row could be:

 `Id` = 2, 
Type = 'mascotcategory'
  `EntryId` = 52,
  `LanguageId` = 1,
  `Value` = 'ici'  

EntryId is the actual id of mascots or mascotcategories tables, while localizationdata.Type means if it is mascot or mascotcategory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how optimal this is, but I believe it works:

First, reduce the two types of localization down to one common type:

```
var mascotNameLocalized = from ld in db.localizationdata
                          where ld.Type == "mascot"
                          group ld by ld.EntryId into ldg
                          select new { MascotId = ldg.Key, Words = ldg.Select(g => g.Value) };
var mascotCategoriesLocalized = from ld in db.localizationdata
                                where ld.Type == "mascotcategory"
                                join mc in db.mascotcategories on ld.EntryId equals mc.Id
                                join m in db.mascots on mc.Id equals m.MascotCategoryId into mj
                                where mj.Any()
                                from m in mj
                                group ld by m.Id into ldg
                                select new { MascotId = ldg.Key, Words = ldg.Select(g => g.Value) };
```

Then combine them into one common list:

```
var mascotsLocalized = from m in mascotNameLocalized.Concat(mascotCategoriesLocalized)
                       group m by m.MascotId into mg
                       select new { MascotId = mg.Key, Words = mg.SelectMany(m2 => m2.Words).ToList() };
```

Then find all mascots that match all the search terms:

```
var srch = "bleu ici";
var srchwords = srch.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var ans = from m in mascotsLocalized
          where srchwords.All(sw => m.Words.Contains(sw))
          select m.MascotId;
```